# How to change border cell based on Date Matching with a specific Date into a Range?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to change border format of a specific cell if date is matching with the range for each row.

For below example, my expectation is to have :

- **Row 1**

  - Green border on the cell matching with 02/11
  - Red border on the cell matching with 05/11
- **Row 2**

  - Green border on the cell matching with 15/11
- **Row 3**

  - Green border on the cell matching with 10/11
  - Red border on the cell matching with 15/11

[image]

Do you know if it is possible to get this kind of behavior? Should I use Conditional Formatting with specific formula?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you need Conditional formatting.
I assume that you have *dates* in your column headers (formatted as dd/MM)

[image]

The first condition checks if the column date (D4) equals Date1 from the according row. You have to fix the row for the column date (D$4) and the column for the Date1 ($B5).

What you propably won't like: you can only apply a very thin borders via conditional formatting :-(